# Can Linux Bash scripts respond to install options

Tags: linux, bash, installation, redhat

I need to script the installation of a number of products on Redhat Linux
I am installing from previously downloaded tar files that each contain their own specific install.sh.
My problem is that by executing the install.sh scripts a number of questions are asked such as ... 
a). Accept license
b). set default path(s)
c). do i wish to start service
etc...
Can Bash detect these questions and respond correctly? or do i require another linux based product/function?
For windows based installs i have used AutoItScript.
What are my options on Linux Redhat?

Comment: You need to check whether those scripts accept command line arguments.

Comment: Looks like they DO NOT accept CLA's. Does that mean i am stuck?

Comment: Or you could look into `TCL/Expect` to sort out your interactive automations.

Comment: I am so close to getting this to work. using the cat command i can "almost" get my first script to run fed from a command.txt file. my only issue is the first response i need to send to my script is in response to a "less" command <code>less -E -m -Pm"Press q to quit." $1</code>. to get past this request i have to type q manually, then the rest of my command.txt file is read as i expect and the install completes OK. What do i need to enter in my command.txt file to satisfy the less command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To establish whether the scripts support any command line options, you can:

- Read the readme file of the software, if there is one. This should explain any options.
- Read the top of the `install.sh` script. Usually options are at least listed there.
- Read the code itself, which might be a lot of work.

Once you have established that the scripts do not support options, the standard way of automating this would be with an `expect` script. See for example [automating install.sh script using an expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329642/automating-install-sh-script-using-an-expect-script).

Depending on how the install script works, you *may* be able to send it commands on standard input. For example, if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> and lastly <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, you can try the following:

```
printf %s $'\t\ny\n' | ./install.sh
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at my issue. I have confirmed my install scripts do not accept any command line arguments. It sounds like expect is what i need, sadly due to my sites security restrictions i am unable to install it/use it.

Comment: just like to feedback the printf option saved me LOTS of pain. really nice work